# Trying to upload to heroku I am getting a parse error in my json file

Tags: json, heroku, package.json

```
{
  "name": "deployingdemo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
error-> "start": "node app.js",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^6.11.3",
    "express": "^10.16.3"
  }
}
```

remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: parse error: Expected separator between values at line 8, column 8
remote:  !     Unable to parse package.json

Comment: Remove the trailing comma.

Comment: @jonrsharpe removed the comma, same error message

Comment: I got it figured out.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Validate your JSON here:

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

```
{
  "name": "deployingdemo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^6.11.3",
    "express": "^10.16.3"
  }
}
```

When removing the `,` after `"start": "node app.js"` I'm not getting any error or info messages.

In case Heroku gets confused you can try: Replacing `\"` with `'` or just remove the `test` line.